# Are there any apps for learning Uyghur?

Tags: electronic-resources, uyghur

I am looking for apps or possibly websites (if they feature gamification) for learning basic Uyghur. Do such apps/sites exist?

Answer (score 1):

Tatoeba has thousands of sentences in Uyghur: https://tatoeba.org/spa/sentences/show_all_in/uig/und

After learning the basics, you can translate those sentences to your native language. The gamification is in seeing the number of sentences without a translation to your native language decrease. There is no levelling or point infrastructure.

Anki has some decks for acquiring vocabulary: https://ankiweb.net/shared/decks/Uyghur . There are no levels or such, but you can see the number of remaining cards decrease, so, again, there is a clear measure of progress.